# lodash.throttle - throttled method not being called?

Tags: javascript, lodash, throttling

I have an event listener, for which I am trying wrap with `lodash.throttle`:

```
import throttle from "lodash.throttle"

const throttledHandleResize = () => { 

    return(throttle(() => {
        console.log("resizing...");
    }, 200));
};

window.addEventListener("resize", throttledHandleResize);
```

The console does not log my string. The method works if I do not try to wrap it with `throttle`.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a function that returns the throttled function.  Every time `resize` occurs, you're creating a *new* throttled function.  Just use the throttled function:

```
import throttle from "lodash.throttle"

const throttledHandleResize = throttle(() => {
        console.log("resizing...");
    }, 200);

window.addEventListener("resize", throttledHandleResize);
```